# Register form doesn't work on production mode (NextJS & Prisma)

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm actually on simple login and register API, I'm using NextJS and Prisma.

Every API urls worked on my local machine and on the server (Plesk) except the register form, it sends me a **502 Bad Gateway** error when all fields are filled. And if I try to register an existing user, it sends response with the status and the message that I defined, so the API url used on the submit is good.

When the app is on the server the queries *findUnique* and *update* worked fine, but when I use *create* query, the error 502 appears.

I've tried to comment the *create* query for the production mode and the response was good, `status 201`.

Here my Nginx proxy :

```
location ~ / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

The submit function :

```
onSubmit: async (values: IFormik) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const resp = await fetch('api/auth/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          firstname: values.firstname,
          lastname: values.lastname,
          email: values.email,
          phone: values.phone,
          password: values.password,
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });

      const json = await resp.json();
      const status = resp.status;

      if (status === 201 && json.isCreated) {
        formikRegister.resetForm();
        formikRegister.setFieldValue('phone', '');
        setErrorMessage(null);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setSuccessMessage(
          'Your account has been created, you can login'
        );
      } else {
        setSuccessMessage(null);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setErrorMessage(json.message);
      }
    }
```

And the register API code :

```
export default withSession(
  async (req: NextIronRequest, res: NextApiResponse): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const { email, password, firstname, lastname, phone } = req.body;
        const prisma = new PrismaClient({
          log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
        });

        await prisma.user
          .findUnique({
            where: {
              email: email,
            },
          })
          .then(async (user) => {
            if (!user) {
              bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then(async (hash) => {
                if (hash) {
                  const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
                    data: {
                      firstName: firstname,
                      lastName: lastname,
                      email: email,
                      phone: phone,
                      password: hash,
                      token: '',
                      createdAt: new Date(),
                      roleId: 1,
                      isValidated: false,
                    },
                  });
                  res.status(201).send({ isCreated: true, newUser });
                  resolve();
                } else {
                  return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Error in password',
                  });
                }
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(409).send({
                message: 'Account already exists',
              });
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            return res.status(400).send(err);
            reject(err);
          });
      } else {
        return res.status(405).send({ message: 'Something wrong happened' });
        reject();
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Honestly i don't know anymore where to looking for to fix this issue.
Let me know if you need more information about my project.

Comment: Do you API works properly? Check it with postman.

Comment: @illiachill yes I checked on Postman there is the same error status for register. This is so crazy because the login, the reset password and the check if user is already existing work but not the create user...

Comment: So you need to check only your API, problem is there. What is the error postman says? And where your API is hosted? Localhost?

Comment: Have you tried to catch and log the error that you get on the server? Otherwise it's rather difficult to pinpoint what might be going wrong.

Comment: @illiachill when API is on Localhost everything is ok, the user is create in database but when API is hosted the error is ``` 502 Bad Gateway ``` and only for register service the others work properly

Comment: So 502 Gateway tell you have invalid response. For test, set to your response "status" with no text and see what happends. like this res.status(401).json({ error: "Ysomething bad happend" });

Comment: @TasinIshmam my app is hosted on Plesk server and I don't really know where I can find the result of my log

Comment: @illiachill nothing different happens but I found the proxy logs and i've got this error : `14447#0: *3294 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: InternalIP, server: ExternalIP, request: "POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth/register", host: "neobank.youseeme.pro"`

Comment: @illiachill and @TasinIshmam I finally fixed the issue ! It was in my database my `updatedAt` doesn't received the data expected... Thanks for your help anyway guys !